# Slidetoggle and change div background color on div click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

So let's say I have multiple div's on a page with the ID of "Toggle".
and in every div there are two other divs.

1. "Headline" This is always visible.
2. "Comment" This toggles on/off when the headline is clicked on (default is off).

How would I do this with jquery? I got it working, but only with one on the page.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#toggle').on('click', function () {
          $(this).find('#comment').slideToggle(100);
        });
    });
</script>
```

(perhaps this is another question, but I would also like the "headline" div's background to be changed to blue when it is clicked (and the comment is dropped down) and revert when "headline" is clicked again, sliding the comments up)

Comment: First thing's first: Because IDs are unique identifiers, you cannot apply an ID to multiple elements on the same page. This is 'illegal' so to speak, and will render most anything in jQuery trying to target it useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment above, jQuery targeting will fail (or at the very least not behave as expected) if use an ID more than once. Use classes for styling and targeting in this case, or use unique IDs per 'toggle' module.

Alright, here's your [Codepen example](http://cdpn.io/nscgy) :)

Core components [expanded styling available in Codepen sketch]

**HTML**

```
<div class='toggle'>
  <h3 class='headline'>My headline</h3>
  <div class='comments'>
    <ul>
      <li>Comment 1</li>
      <li>Comment 2</li>
      <li>Comment 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.comments {
  display: none;
}

.comments.open {
  display: block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.headline').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).next('.comments').toggleClass('open');
});
```

**Alternate jQuery slideToggle**

```
$(this).next('.comments').slideToggle(); // instead of toggling a class
```

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE:**

**Pure jQuery background-color toggle**

```
var active = false;

$('.header').on('click', function(){
  if(active == false) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    active = true;
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    active = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: So I tried what you said, and it didn't work, but I substituted your jquery with this:     <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.toggle').on('click', function () {
              $(this).find('.comment').slideToggle(125);
            });
        });
    </script> And it worked --- but I still can't figure out how to make the background toggle on click

Comment: Did you check out Codepen sketch: http://codepen.io/kunalbhat/full/nscgy ? The example on how to toggle bg color is in there.

Comment: Simplest way would be to add a class like I did in the CSS that gives your headline a blue background. Then simply `toggleClass` on click for `.headline` to something like `.headline.blue`

Answer (score 0):

It is working with only one because you have inserted id='toggle' instead use class so it will work on all and in the case of sliding try out this http://jsfiddle.net/MohammadHamza/F64n9/'>Fiddle.